# Display different types of media?

Tags: angularjs

I do have an Array of different media resources:

- Images
- Youtoube URLs
- Simple Text

They are saved with an URL/Content attribute and an type attribute (`image`/`youtube`/`text`).

When updating `$scope.media` I want to display the correct HTML template. I have this solution:

```
 <div ng-show="page.media.type == 'text'">{{$scope.media.paragraph}}</div>
 <img ng-show="page.media.type == 'image'" ng-src="{{$scope.media.url}}"/>
 <iframe ng-show="page.media.type == 'youtube'" ng-src="{{scope.media.url}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I would like to have this as separated HTML template files for each content type. The page which contains this is already a partial template for a `<div ng-view></div>` area in the main index.html and the media view is also already inside of an `ng-switch-when` switch.

Therefor I don't want to add a **nested** `ng-view` or `ng-switch` to include the media templates. Is there any other way of having separate HTML templates triggered by $scope changes?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude), and its capability to include template html either from server or from within the page.

```
<div ng-include src="templateIdentifier"></div>
```

The `src` property can be an expression, and hence changes to model `src` binding would change the template dynamically.

So you can do a watch such as

```
$scope.$watch('$scope.media',function(media) {
    $scope.templateIdentifier='template-'+media.type;
});
```

This is how you would define the template if defined inline

```
<script type="text/ng-template" class="template" id="template-text">
    {{$scope.media.paragraph}}
</script
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test this. I wanted to have the "template choosing logic" to be on the template side and not on the application (controller) side... But this is still a nice solution!

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by template side?

Comment: In my controller code I only want to set the media type but not have any if-else switch to choose a template according to the type. This micro logic if-else template choosing code should be in the template, partial or any ng-* file. But not in the controller.js

Comment: if the partial html snippet can be retrieved using HTTP GET (these templates are exposed over http url) then you can, or you need to embed then in script sections.